# My python based discord bot is not responding to any commands entered, and the initial method is not printing anything

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

When I iniatiate my discord bot,the `on_ready` method does not work. The bot comes online,but none of the code in the method prints in the command line. Also,the info command fails to work. This is all code that worked previously with another bot that I wrote, so I'm unsure as to what is failing to work. The code is included below.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord


client = discord.Client()


TOKEN = "insert token here"
description = "Bot that does things"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", description="testbot")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print("-----------------")
    print("Developed by")
    print("me")


@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Commands", description="Here are the commands:", color=0xFFFF00
    )
    embed.add_field(name="meme", value="gives you a  meme", inline=True)
    print("Cmd entered")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because you have both `client` (a `discord.Client` instance) and `bot` (a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instance) defined. If you remove `client` and change `client.run()` to `bot.run()`, the bot should work.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord


TOKEN = "insert token here"
description = "Bot that does things"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", description="testbot")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    ...

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    ...


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Yes and commands require at least the messages intents which is missing too.

Comment: @ChrisDewa I think message intents are set to `True`, by default, unless I am mistaken

Comment: It's true, default is everything enabled but privileged. Thanks for the info